# Xcode letters beside files in Project Navigator

Tags: xcode

[image]

What are the significance of the letters beside the files in the Project Navigator? (e.g M,A)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Those letters beside files in the Project Navigator of Xcode show the status of files that are under version control systems, such as SVN or Git. So, for instance:

- M - means the file has changed and it should be merged into SCM
- A - means this is a new file and should be added to SCM
- U - means this is a newer version of a file on SCM and you need to update it
- ? - means the file has not been added to source control
- etc...

P.S. You can find list of statuses (at least for SVN) [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html)

Comment: @jsetting32 D means the item has been locally Deleted. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901431/5866353 and  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html

Comment: Discover more options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863683/what-do-the-m-and-a-icons-in-the-project-navigator-of-xcode-4-mean-when-i-cr/#answer-38842852

Answer (score 19):

A - Added (This is a new file that has been added to the repository)

C - Conflict (There is a conflict in the file)

D - Deleted (a file has been deleted)

M - Modified (An existing file has been changed)

R - Renamed (The file has been renamed)

U - Untracked (The file is new or has been changed but has not been added to the repository yet)

Comment: @Georgia--

What about the symbol "-" ?

Comment: @rattletrap99 a dash is for a directory/group that contains more letters when it is expanded

Answer (score 0):

Well, my project is not part of source control, yet the same icons are there.
So there must be more to it.

UPDATE: Bacalso Vincent is correct, I did enable GIT on creating the project.
I had completely forgotten about that though.

Comment: maybe you checked enabled git, during creation of your project