# ? mark for AppDelegate.m file in Xcode 13

Tags: xcode, react-native

After recreating `AppDelegate.m` for React Native 0.68 project, there is `?` appearing after the file (see image below). Does it spell trouble? There are currently error of duplicate for x86 (MacOS 12.4 on intel silicon) when building for `AppDelegate.o and main.o`.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the "M" and "A" icons in the Project Navigator of Xcode 4 mean when I create a new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863683/what-do-the-m-and-a-icons-in-the-project-navigator-of-xcode-4-mean-when-i-cr)

Comment: Sure it does and thank you!